# Homotopy groups of unitary groups

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0301192v1) I found some explicit generators of homotopy groups of unitary groups, for example

$\pi_3[SU_2]$:

$\begin{bmatrix}z_1\\z_2\end{bmatrix}$$\rightarrow $$\begin{bmatrix}z_1 &-\bar{z_2}\\z_2 &z_1\end{bmatrix}$

and

$\pi_5[SU_3]$:

$\begin{bmatrix}z_1\\z_2\\z_3\end{bmatrix}$$\rightarrow $$\begin{bmatrix}z_1+\bar{z}_3z_2 & -\bar{z}_3^2 & -\bar{z}_2+\bar{z}_3\bar{z}_1\\z^2_2 & z_1-z_2\bar{z}_3 & z_3+z_2\bar{z}_1 \\ -z_3+\bar{z}_1z_2 & -\bar{z}_2-\bar{z}_1\bar{z}_3 & \bar{z}^2_1\end{bmatrix}$.

I am in search of explicit 2x2 unitary matrices of this form for $\pi_4[SU_2]$ and $\pi_5[SU_2]$, but haven't been able to find them (maybe they don't exist). If anyone knows of a paper containing them or an easy method of constructing them, I would greatly appreciate it.

Many thanks,

Pascal